# Align UIBarButtonItem Back Button

Tags: ios, swift, uibarbuttonitem

Here is what I have in my viewDidLoad method:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorImage = UIImage(named: "back")?.imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysOriginal)
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = UIImage(named: "back")?.imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysOriginal)
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: nil, action: nil)
```

This shows a custom image that works when clicking the button, but the button is pushed up against the status bar. **How do I lower the button?**

Comment: Can you show me the screenshot for this?

Comment: http://s16.postimg.org/vu43tg291/i_OS_Simulator_Screen_Shot_Nov_17_2015_12_15_56.png

Comment: Could it have something to do with the size?

Comment: Yes. Your image is too big. You need follow the Apple docs: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TransitionGuide/Bars.html .height 44 points for @2x